# How to save sent messages in same folder as message being replied to?

Tags: macos, mail.app, email

One of my favorite features back when I used Outlook was the option to save sent emails in the same folder as the message being replied to. For example, if I had moved a message to folder A and was replying to that, my reply was saved in A, not Sent. (If I replied to a message in my Inbox, my reply went to the default Sent folder.)

This made it really easy to see an entire thread when I came back to it later. This workflow is a huge time-saver for me and is the only thing I miss from Outlook. Right now, I manually move sent messages to the folder with related messages which is tedious. Is there a way to recreate this feature from Outlook with Mac Mail? (I'm using Mac Mail 6.2 on OSX 10.8.2).

Comment: I was wondering if you have had a chance to take a look at my answer below. I managed to mimic the Outlook feature you miss with AppleScript and Services. Please let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, jaume. I haven't had a chance to try it yet although I appreciate the time you put into such a thorough answer. I have since discovered the "Show related messages" button in the Mail toolbar. Although this doesn't solve the original problem I stated, it does make Mail act a bit like GMail where related messages (i.e. the same thread) are all shown together no matter what folder they are in. This seems to be a viable workaround for now.

Comment: I'm happy you found a workaround. If you ever miss the "reply and move to folder" functionality and try my answer below, please post whether it worked for you.

Answer (score 5):

Mail can be extended to mimic pretty closely the feature you mention from Outlook.

OS X provides a feature called **services** that can be used to extend the functionality of an application (see http://www.macosxautomation.com/services/learn/index.html for more information).

I will use Automator and AppleScript to create a service that moves sent messages to the folder of the message being replied to, and then assign the standard reply keyboard shortcut (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) to the service:

- Close Mail.
- Open Automator in folder `Applications` and choose Service:

[image]

- Select *Utilities* under *Library* and drag *Run AppleScript* to the empty pane on the right:

[image]

- Configure the service to receive no input in Mail:

[image]

- Replace the contents of the *Run AppleScript* action with:

  ```
   on run {input, parameters}

   tell application "Mail"
       try
           (* Get selected messages or exit *)
           set messageSelection to selection
           set selectedMessage to item 1 of messageSelection
           set replyMessage to reply selectedMessage opening window yes
           set messageID to message id of selectedMessage
           set currentMailbox to mailbox of selectedMessage
       on error
           return
       end try
       repeat
           (* Wait until reply message is sent *)
           delay 2
           try
               if replyMessage is not visible then exit repeat
           on error
               exit repeat
           end try
       end repeat
       synchronize with (account of currentMailbox)
       (* Wait while reply message is being sent *)
       delay 10
       (* Loop over all sent messages *)
       set sentMailbox to sent mailbox of application "Mail"
       set allSentMessages to messages of sentMailbox
       repeat with sentMessage in allSentMessages
           if source of sentMessage contains messageID then
               set mailbox of sentMessage to currentMailbox
               return
           end if
       end repeat
   end tell

   return input
   end run
  ```
- Save with a descriptive name like *Reply and Move Sent Message to Current Folder*. The service will be saved to `~/Library/Services/`. This is what the service looks like:

[image]

- Open System Preferences, select the *Keyboard* preference pane and then the *Keyboard Shortcuts* tab.
- Select *Application Shortcuts*, press the <kbd>+</kbd> button and change for application Mail the shortcut assigned to menu item Reply to <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>. We change it to avoid conflicts when assigning <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to the service below:

[image]

- Select *Services*, scroll down to the service you previously added and set the keyboard shortcut to <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

- Open Mail. Notice that Reply's shortcut is no longer <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, but <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

- Also notice that there is a new service, accessible with <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>:

[image]

- Now select a message in a folder, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>, type your reply and send it, in a few seconds you should see the sent message appear in the folder.

**Changing the service to "Reply All"**:

[Olivier](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/211506/olivier) has asked in a comment how to expand the Automator Service to reply to the sender and other recipients:

1. If you are using a recent version of macOS, choose "Quick Action" in Automator.
2. Replace the following line in the AppleScript above:

   ```
   set replyMessage to reply selectedMessage opening window yes
   ```

   with:

   ```
   set replyMessage to reply selectedMessage opening window yes reply to all yes
   ```
3. Change the application shortcut for "Reply All" (<kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>) to something like <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and bind <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to the service.

**The script has some limitations and side effects:**

- The service can't tell canceled and sent messages apart. So, if you press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and then change your mind and close the window, the service will continue executing and check your Sent folder for matching IDs.
- AppleScript doesn't offer any means of getting a list of replies to a message. My workaround is to get the message id of the message being replied to and search it in the sent messages.
- The sent message can't be moved while being downloaded. AppleScript doesn't return any error message if that's the case, so I added a 10-second delay. A 5-second delay was not reliable in my tests, adapt it to your needs if necessary.
- While the service searches the Sent folder, Mail slows down.

Comment: Sorry if my question was not clear. I already have Mail grouping messages by conversation. Let me see if this helps: when I have a thread in a folder and I reply to the thread, I want my reply to go in the same folder, NOT the Sent folder. That way, my reply shows up in the thread as well - not just everyone else's replies to the thread. Does that make sense?

Comment: You are already using conversations, don't you see your own replies along with other people's replies? Anyway, if conversations isn't exactly what you are looking for I haven't found any way (I checked Preferences>Rules) to automatically move sent messages to the folder the original message was located...

Comment: No, my replies don't get added to the conversation as a separate item. If someone else replies, there is link at the bottom of their email that says "See More from Dave Burns". Clicking on that does show my response. But what I want is the actual email that I sent put in the same folder.

Comment: The functionality you are looking for can be achieved using AppleScript and Services. I've completely rewritten the answer, please have a look and let me know whether it works for you.

Comment: Awesome little script however is there a way to make it "Reply All" instead of simply reply? I must admit my AppleScript Fu is weak-sauce.. .I have tried obvious tweak but none worked for me.

Comment: @Olivier I'm glad you found my 9-year-old answer useful! Could you try changing `set replyMessage to reply selectedMessage opening window yes` to `set replyMessage to reply selectedMessage opening window yes reply to all yes`. You will probably want to change the application shortcut for "Reply All" (<shift><command>R) to something like <shift><option><command>R and bind <shift><command>R to the service, too.

Comment: @jaume amazing, yes it works perfectly fine! Thank you so much. For those reading this and wanting to apply to Monterey, instead of "services" you should set up in Automator a "Quick Action". All other steps are identical. Such an incredibly useful little script that avoids me 1,000 daily paper cuts.