# How to save the sent items in the folder where I'm replying from, in MS Outlook on Mac?

Tags: email, ms-office

Same question has been asked before on how to fix this in the default Mail app on Mac, but I'm wondering if there is a solution also to the Microsoft Outlook app on Mac?

This is the link I found before and can confirm the the answer provided worked for the Mac Mail App:
[How to save sent messages in same folder as message being replied to?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79604/how-to-save-sent-messages-in-same-folder-as-message-being-replied-to)

Answer (score 0):

All I found out is, that this feature is not available for Outlook for Mac.

Comment: Do you have a link to an online source that says this is so?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).