# Mac Mail Sent Email Folder is a mess

Tags: mac, email

How can I tidy up my sent email folder in Mac Mail automatically ? I would like to move all sent emails to a relevant IMAP-folder I generated for a topic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save sent messages in same folder as message being replied to?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/79604/how-to-save-sent-messages-in-same-folder-as-message-being-replied-to)

Comment: No it does not. This guideline helps to avoid the mess whilst I search for a solution which is dealing when it is too late and many emails are already in the sent folder.

Comment: What have you done to figure this out yourself, but failed? There are many options you can try, such as creating folders/mailboxes, and through the search feature, find emails by subject line, or sender, or some other criteria, and move emails into those folders. One thing to consider, first, is to use the same search features and thin out the cruft you don't need to keep.

Comment: I prefer to have all emails in the relevant folder rather than using any of the suggested ways. I am used to MS Outlook I find this the best way.